# VBA: How to Space Items evenly in a Userform List?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

For a starter, I have the following in a loop:

```
lstResults.AddItem Range("A" & row).value & vbTab & _
                   Range("B" & row).value & vbTab & _
                   Range("C" & row).value
```

I want to replace `vbTab` with some other function that will give me **consistent** spacing, regardless the width of character. My results need to look something like:

```
Title1       Title2       Title3
12           34           56
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't loop through your source range, put it into a 2D variant array instead:

```
Dim source As Variant
source = Range("A1:C10").Value ' assuming your loop boundaries here.. adjust accordingly
```

Then, configure the listbox columns:

```
lstResults.ColumnCount = 3
lstResults.ColumnWidths = "50,50,50" ' adjust as you see fit
lstResults.ColumnHeads = True
```

Now fill the list with the array:

```
lstResults.List = source
```

Done :)

Comment: Dope Result! :))

Comment: @CarloSantana hmm, just tested it, the headers aren't coming up the way I meant them to.. Perhaps using a `ListObject` (aka table) as a source can change that, see [this post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/140995/23788) for examples. ColumnHeads display properly when using a `RowSource`, not a `List`. See what you get with  `Range("A1:C10").Address` instead of a 2D array.

Comment: what would be the new syntax for `RowSource`?

Comment: Yeah I intended the first row to be taken as column headings. RowSource will do that.

Answer (score 0):

Set the list properties `ColumnCount` to `3` and `ColumnWidths`  to `100,100,100`   - either in code or in the form designer. The values are in points, and depending on your locale, they might be separated by `;` instead of `,`

Comment: so instead of <vbTab>, I add <;> or <,>?

Comment: No - keep the tabs. Just set some properties on the list control.

Comment: I changed columncount and column width, same result